# Try to copy FireFox bookmarks

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to copy my Firefox bookmarks with a batch file and save it on a directoy.
It does not work
any Idea?

```
  cd %AppData%
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%%j
cd profiles\%var1%
if exist d:\bookmarks\places.sqlite copy d:\bookmarks\places.sqlite
```

Comment: *It does not work.* What does that **exactly** mean? Errors? Nothing happens? Unicorns appear? Something else?

Comment: It started my firefox and run the command but It does not copy my firefox profil

Comment: What is the output then when you run the bits after `c:`? I mean, echo is on so it should show you what %var1% is for example and if that for loop gets executed at all.

Comment: Why are you starting Firefox at all? Also `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming` can be replaced with `%AppData%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop is not correct. You'll only get the latest profile.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call set var1=%%j
cd profiles\%var1%
if exist d:\backupbookmarks\places.sqlite copy d:\backupbookmarks\places.sqlite
```

Instead do this:

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('findstr /l ".default" profiles.ini') do call :profile %%j
rem other code
GOTO :EOF

:profile
pushd profiles\%1
if exist d:\backupbookmarks\places.sqlite copy d:\backupbookmarks\places.sqlite 
popd
GOTO :EOF
```